# image processing in pascal

Tags: image, image-processing, pascal

Please, anyone help me to solve my problem "who can I get the image data in pascal language", I mean who can I read or display an image in pascal language

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick, a popular image processing library, has [Pascal bindings](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/PascalMagick).

Answer (score 0):

try to use PE explorer , to find it , but i think it is ASCII encoded ,
https://pe-explorer.software.informer.com/